# Difference between millisecond value when writing and reading back MySQL DATE using JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc

I call JDBC `setDate` with `new java.sql.Date(0)`

I do JDBC `getDate` and call `java.sql.Date.getTime()`. It returns -19800000 (which is epoch, but represented as a millisecond number relative to my timezone).

I am dealing with milliseconds, because thats what is received in the REST Api.

I'm using MySql DATE column and MySQL Connector 5.1

**Edit:** Adding some code to summarize the problem

```
//SQL INSERT INTO DATE_TEST(STARTDATE) VALUES(?);
//Setting the date
ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(0));
ps.executeUpdate();

//SQL SELECT STARTDATE FROM DATE_TEST
Date entryDate = rs.getDate(1);
Long lEntryDate = entryDate.getTime();
//Now lEntryDate is -19800000
```

Any idea why this is happening..

- Is it because the column is a DATE column?
- Is it because it considers input as UTC and assumes output is required relative to current time zone?

Edit 2: 
I added more complete code which reproduces the issue.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DateMySqlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hdb", "root", "");

            //Insert
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO DATE_TEST(DATEFIELD) VALUES(?)");
            java.sql.Date inDate = new java.sql.Date(0);
            System.out.println("Write milliseconds: " + inDate.getTime());
            ps.setDate(1, inDate);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            //Read
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT DATEFIELD FROM DATE_TEST");
            while (rs.next()){
                java.sql.Date outDate = rs.getDate(1);
                System.out.println("Read milliseconds: " + outDate.getTime());
            }

            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Write milliseconds: 0
Read milliseconds: -19800000
```

Comment: That is what you are doing. `0` milliseconds since epoch, is twelve midnight on January 1, 1970 UTC.

Comment: Right... I think the question is slightly wrong. When I read it back it says the milliseconds in my timezone?

Comment: When I set, it thinks i'm supplying milliseconds in UTC. When I read, it thinks I expect milliseconds in IST.

Comment: @Teddy Your Question seems confused. Please post a minimal example of actual code, actual inputs and actual output.

Comment: @BasilBourque The actual code is spanning multiple classes. I tried to summarize the problem in the edit.

Comment: Looks to me to be a MySQL issue. I just added back the default timezone offset milliseconds after reading the date.  TimeZone.getDefault().getOffset(date.getTime())

Comment: If I recall correctly, with Connector/J 5,1 you should be able to store a `java.time.Instant` to the datebase and retrieve it as an `Instant` again (and if not, you may consider a newer Connector/J). I would be curious if this eliminated the problem or not. It may be worth it no matter if it does since `Date` is outdated (no pun intended) and the modern classes like `Instant` are much nicer to work with.

Comment: Perhaps try `Date entryDate = rs.getDate(1, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));`

Comment: @Teddy [MCVE - How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks... I'll take a look at java.time.Instant

Comment: @GordThompson That looks like the right fix! I am able tell the driver to give me milliseconds relative to UTC. It returns milliseconds 0 now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fact that you are using `setDate` and `getDate` without the optional `Calendar` arguments, so those methods are interpreting date/time values in your local time zone (IST, UTC+5:30). Specifically,

- `new java.sql.Date(0)` produces a date/time value of `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, which `setDate` interprets as `1970-01-01 05:30:00 IST`.
- When MySQL saves the value to a `DATE` column it truncates the time part, so you get `1970-01-01`. That's okay.
- However, when you *retrieve* the value `getDate(1)` interprets the date/time value as `1970-01-01 00:00:00 IST`, which is `1969-12-31 18:30:00 UTC` or 19800000 ms before the epoch.

To avoid that problem you could use

```java
Date entryDate = rs.getDate(1, Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")));
```

which will interpret `1970-01-01` as `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`, as you desire.

Comment: IMO the MySQL driver is misbehaving. As I understand java.util.Date and any subclass is not meant to have timezone information. The java.util.Date getTime method signature says that it is supposed to give milliseconds since epoch. But, MySQL returns a negative millisecond number which is its way of saying 'epoch is -19,800,000 ms relative to midnight of 1-1-1970 in IST' which is wrong.

Comment: *"MySQL returns a negative millisecond number which is its way of saying 'epoch is -19,800,000 ms relative to midnight of 1-1-1970 in IST' which is wrong"* - No, you've got it backwards. What it is saying is that `1970-01-01 00:00:00 IST`, which is the exact same moment in time as `1969-12-31 18:30:00 UTC`, is -19,800,000 ms relative to the epoch, which is correct.

Comment: Okay, got it now. Thanks. When storage is with timezone, and date-only column, it stores midnight of that timezone.

Comment: So, by passing the calendar what I am saying? "Give me that date relative to UTC" or "Get me that date assuming that date was stored in UTC". Looks like it is the latter... I am overriding the timezone which is stored.

Comment: By passing the Calendar object you're saying "Interpret the date/time value in the time zone specified by the Calendar". If no Calendar object is supplied, JDBC will interpret the date/time value using the default time zone of the JVM under which your Java code is running (IST, in your case).